# Using an Excel Macro/VBA to cut and paste data into a newly created row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to modify a current report which I am running for my company.  The report brings back some basic information on an Event.  At the end of the data, there is one final column which lists the Event Description.  I want to insert a new row above any row which contains "Totals" and then insert Loss Description: Description.

The issue I am running into is that I can't get the "Descriptions" to cut and paste behind Loss Description: in the newly created row.  I can't post an image of the report but the code I'm using will be below.  When I run the Macro, a new row gets created above the Row which contains "Totals" but the column with the description does not cut and paste.  The description is in Column Q of the Excel Spreadsheet and the Loss Description: is being created in Column A.

```
   Sub InsertAdj()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Integer, n As Integer
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Left(Range("A" & i), 6) = "Totals" Then
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    n = WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Lookup("zzzzz", Range("A1:A" & i)), Range("A1:A" & i), 
    0)
    Cells(i, 1) = "Loss Description: " & Cells(n + 1, 16).Value
    Cells(n + 1, 16).ClearContents
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something odd going on on your worksheet where `End(xlUp)` doesn't behave as it should - for some reason it stops on empty cells...

Tested this alternate approach and it works for me on your sample worksheet:

```
Sub InsertAdj()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Integer, n As Integer, descCell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    LR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If Left(sht.Range("A" & i), 6) = "Totals" Then
            sht.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            'end(xlUp) does not work for some reason, so call a function to find the description
            Set descCell = FindDescriptionCell(sht.Cells(i + 1, "Q")) 'call function

            sht.Cells(i, 1) = "Loss Description: " & descCell.Value
            descCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function FindDescriptionCell(c As Range)
    Dim f
    'search up for a value
    Set f = c.EntireColumn.Find(what:="*", after:=c, _
             searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'ensure Find didn't loop back below the start cell
        If f.Row < c.Row Then Set FindDescriptionCell = f
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It looks like this code didn't quite work.  It created the new row and added Loss Description:  Ater Loss Description it added a total dollar figure for the financials in Column N and Column O.  The description which I'm trying to move within Column Q stayed where it was.

Comment: The code created the new row and added Loss Description: but now there's nothing after Loss Description: and the data in Column Q is still there.

Comment: The code you provided seems like it should work so I'm not sure why the data in column Q isn't moving to the newly created row.

Comment: Any merged cells?

Comment: Actually, yes.  So, the first row under the column headings is a merged row.  Also, the Totals row (where we are moving this row down) is a merged row as well.  Unfortunately, this site won't let me paste any pictures so I'll try and describe the report in further detail.  Rows 1-4 are Report Headers.  The report starts on Row 5.  Column A5 does not have a Column Header.  B5 - P5 have Column Headers.  Q5 is empty. A6 has Event Number: 0000000 which is merged through Column P.  The data starts on B7 and the data is listed within the respective columns.  The description is in Q7

Comment: The Totals row is also a merged cell from A-J.  Row 5 will always be the column headers.  Row 6 will always be merged from A6 - P6.  The first row of data will always start on Row 7.  The Totals row will vary depending on how many rows of data we have for that specific Event

Comment: You can upload a screenshot to a hosting site and post the link  - someone will add the image from the link (or at least we can click the link...)

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the report https://i.gyazo.com/5885622db8eb6fe66e102ad64cf0db08.png

Comment: OK that's a lot more complicated than your question suggested...  Will there always be a description for every Total row, and will it always be located one or more rows up from the Total row?

Comment: Yes.  There will always be a new row created above the Totals row which includes Loss Description: Description of the Event.

Comment: I meant will there always be an existing description to pull from when creating the new row, and is that existing description always one or more rows above the Totals row?

Comment: Yes.  There will always be an existing description to pull from when creating the new row.  I would like to have the description always 1 row above the Totals row.  Currently, the code you provided me with creates the new row above each Totals row and enters Loss Description: which is what I'm looking to have going forward.

Comment: I ran the updated code.  It worked for all of the Events where there was only one claim within the Event, like Event A000005 in the screenshot I sent earlier. For the Events where there are more than 1 claim within the Event, it created the new row and added Loss Description but the Description of Event didn't copy over.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what it looked like after running the updated code https://i.gyazo.com/0f3b2e9f8b320f211445c9229132cbe3.png

Comment: See my updates above - added some debug info.  See if you can use the output to make the required adjustments.  Or if you can share a copy of the sheet I will try to fix it...

Comment: I can share a copy of the sheet.  How can I get it to you?